# How to check and end a 2d array of noughts and crosses (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have made a noughts and crosses game using 2D arrays and loops (code is below).I want to end the game once the array is full. I've tried an if statement such as if (board[row][col] = '.') however i'm told this is incompatible as it can't be converted to a boolean. Another idea i have is to count the data entries and end it after 9 goes. However, im new to java and struggling to do these can anyone tell me how to end the game once the array is full?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // declare and intitialise the board
    char[][] board = new char[3][3];

    // initialise all the elements to '.' we use this to indicate that a 
    // square is empty, because a space character would not be visible
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            board[row][col] = '.';  
        }
    }

    //The first player is X
    int placeRow;
    int placeCol;        
    char thisPlayer = 'X';
    boolean finished = false;

    while (!finished) {

        //Display the board
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        // Ask the user where to place the next character
        System.out.println("Character to be placed is " + thisPlayer);
        System.out.print("Enter the row at which you wish to place it> ");
        placeRow = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the column at which you wish to place it> ");
        placeCol = scanner.nextInt();
        if (placeRow < 0 || placeRow > 2 || placeCol < 0 || placeCol > 2  ) {
            finished=true;
        }

        while (!finished) {

            //Display the board
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {  

                }
                System.out.println();
            }  
            board[placeRow][placeCol] = thisPlayer;
            thisPlayer = (thisPlayer == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Incompatible types in an `if` clause

> I've tried an if statement such as if (board[row][col] = '.') however i'm told this is incompatible as it can't be converted to a boolean.

You've been told that, because `=` is the `assignment` operator.

In order to check equality you should use `== equal to` operator:

```
if (board[row][col] == '.') {
    /* do smth */
}
```

I suggest reading the following articles on operators:

- [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)
- [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

### How to stop execution when the board is full

> count the data entries and end it after 9 goes

You have the right idea, you just go through the board at the end of every iteration (just as you do when printing it's content), and check with `!= not equal` operator whether the cells contain anything but dots.

```
// your external loop
while (!finished) {

    /* Displaying the board, prompting for inputs */

    // Calculating number of data entries across the board
    int dataEntries = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != '.') {
                dataEntries ++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Break loop if there are 9 data entries
    if (dataEntries > 8) {
        System.out.println("Board is full, game over.");
        break;
    }
}
```